# Internet Explorer vs Chrome Bug

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, positioning

I have a problem. Please look @ http://www.tengizchevroil.com/ru/news/publications.asp

When you browse this page through Chrome it's OK, Links under the pages are looking good. However, when you browse through IE 8, the links are broken and positions are not good. Is there any way to fix that bug?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, it loads fine for me in IE8. Do you have Compatibility View turned on, by chance? Tools -> Compatibility View

Comment: Could you please PrtScr your view and send me the link of the picture? Because, I've turned CompView on but it still sucks.

Comment: Compatibility View is actually what breaks it for me.

http://imgur.com/ES1au - IE 8 w/o Compatibility View

Comment: WOW! Nice! So, it's IE CV. Thanks, I switched it off and now it works fine! God bless you!

Comment: You should figure out why IE 8 had CV on by default for your page. There are two reasons off the top of my head that this would happen:

1. Browser settings. Under Tools -> Compatibility View Settings you can set certain domains to always have compatibility mode. Some organizations force it for all intranet sites that were built to support older versions of IE.

2. Bad DOCTYPE or some other issue with your markup causing the browser to switch to quirks mode, which I believe (though I may be wrong) in IE 7/8 is CV